# BouncyCastle decrypt output size incorrect

Tags: c#, .net-core, bouncycastle

I am using BouncyCastle.NetCore. At the moment of decryption, it seems the GetOutputSize call returns a larger than the actual required length for the output byte array, with the extra bytes having value '0x00'. 
Before converting it back to objects or strings, I hence need to recreate the byte array with the actual length that I retrieve from the ProcessBytes and DoFinal calls.

Should I be using a different call to get the correct number of bytes beforehand or how should I go about this?

```
    public AesEncryptor()
    {
        // AES - CBC - with default PKCS5/PKCS7 scheme
        _encryptionCipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new CbcBlockCipher(new AesEngine()));
        _decryptionCipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new CbcBlockCipher(new AesEngine()));
    }

    public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] iv, byte[] byteArrayToEncrypt)
    {
        ParametersWithIV keyParamWithIV = new ParametersWithIV(_keyParam, iv, 0, iv.Length);

        byte[] encryptedBytes;
        lock (_encryptionLock)
        {
            _encryptionCipher.Init(true, keyParamWithIV);
            encryptedBytes = new byte[_encryptionCipher.GetOutputSize(byteArrayToEncrypt.Length)];
            int length = _encryptionCipher.ProcessBytes(byteArrayToEncrypt, encryptedBytes, 0);
            _encryptionCipher.DoFinal(encryptedBytes, length);
        }
        return encryptedBytes;
    }

    public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] iv, byte[] byteArrayToDecrypt)
    {
        ParametersWithIV keyParamWithIV = new ParametersWithIV(_keyParam, iv, 0, iv.Length);

        byte[] decryptedBytesReworked;
        lock (_decryptionLock)
        {
            _decryptionCipher.Init(false, keyParamWithIV);
            var decryptedBytes = new byte[_decryptionCipher.GetOutputSize(byteArrayToDecrypt.Length)];
            int length = _decryptionCipher.ProcessBytes(byteArrayToDecrypt, decryptedBytes, 0);
            int newLength = _decryptionCipher.DoFinal(decryptedBytes, length); //Do the final block

            // TODO - incorrect initial byte array length
            decryptedBytesReworked = new byte[length + newLength];
            Array.Copy(decryptedBytes, decryptedBytesReworked, decryptedBytesReworked.Length);
        }

        return decryptedBytesReworked;
    }
```

Cheers.

Comment: There is different encryption options and you are using one the adds padding to make the size of a multiple length (usually 32,64,128, or256).

Comment: I see... I was under the impression the decryption should invert/remove the padding; I'll have a look at the BufferedBlockCipher.

Comment: It should if you are using the same encryption method in both encrypting and decrypting.  It looks like you aren't using the same options in both encrypting and decrypting.

Comment: `GetOutputSize()` returns a number that is guaranteed to be large enough to hold the answer, in other words the actual size is <= `GetOutputSize()` . For some modes nothing more precise is possible, for example with PKCS7 padding you cannot know the actual size of the plaintext until *after* it's been decrypted. So you must pay attention to the lengths returned and resize the answer accordingly. I don't see how this is a problem though.

Comment: I thought there might be a way I didn't know of to get the exact length before the decryption - but your explanation makes total sense, thanks. It just seems a waste that I basically need to create an extra copy of the byte array, to return the correct byte array for further processing.